# How can I specialize a typedef and its implicit type differently?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, specialization

I have something like this:

```
typedef int AnotherType;
template <typename T> Func( T Value );

// And I want to specialize these two cases separately:

template <> bool Func<int>( int Value ) {...}
template <> bool Func<AnotherType>( AnotherType Value ) {...}
```

I don't really need to specialize for int, what I really need is to execute a different function for AnotherType.  And I cannot change the definition of AnotherType or the base function.

Overloading doesn't help either because of SFINAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp).

Comment: I can't include an external library at this point.  But I think the idea of the strong typedef is exactly what I was thinking of doing: a class that acts exactly like my underlying type.  Although the Boost strong typedef seems limited; it would probably not work even if I could include it.

Comment: This is as close to a solution as I will get it seems.  For my particular case, it turned out to be the least bad option too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.  When you typedef you create an alias for a type, not an actual type in and of itself.  The compiler will treat both the same.  That's why:

```
typedef int Foo;
typedef int Bar;

Bar bar = 1;
Foo foo = bar;
```

Will compile.  They're both ints.

Comment: I think the OP knows this, IMO he's asking if there's a way around it when using templates. +1 for a correct answer though.

Comment: Indeed I know that.  But I am desperate :(

Comment: @Frigg Unfortunately it's just not possible for the reasons I've stated above.  About the only way around it is to create another function that you manually call for objects of that type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't have the compiler treat int and AnotherType differently. All typedef does is alias types -- it doesn't actually create a new type; by definition of the typedef construct, the compiler will treat int and AnotherType equivalenty in all cases.

If you need to have a type with just an int that IS treated differently, you should probably just make a single-member `struct`.  Most operations on the contained int will compile to the same machine code as a bare int, but now your data type can have its own template specializations and such.

Comment: Not an option because all the existing code around AnotherType will not work.

Answer (score 1):

*And I cannot change the definition of AnotherType or the base function.*

Then you're screwed.  Sorry.  The only option you really have, a strong typedef, is not an option if you can't change the definition to use a strong typedef.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will treat both of the specializations as exactly the same, since `AnotherType` is just another name for `int`. You say you don't need to specialize for `int`, so just remove that specialization completely and let it specialize on whatever type `AnotherType` happens to work out to.

Comment: Can't do that.  I need to do something DIFFERENT for AnotherType, than for int.